# Views Context Filters Hierarchical Cascade / Inheritance

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a hierarchal taxonomy but I'm having trouble getting a view of it to do what I want, and while it seems logical to me, I'm not sure it is even possible.

The hierarchy is geographical areas:
Country>State>County>City

I want a view that can take the hierarchy out of the URL (ie USA/Idaho/Adams/Meadows) which I have achieved using three filters, each a reference to the first 3 iterations of the parentage...

The problem is I don't want that requirement for ALL the levels of parentage... I want something like:

```
if arg1 arg1 == taxo:parent:parent:parent:field
  if arg2 compare arg2 == taxo:parent:parent:field
    if arg3 compare arg3 == taxo:parent:parent:field
      if arg4 compare arg4 == taxo:field
      else compare arg3 == taxo:field
    else compare arg2 == taxo:parent:field
      if arg3 compare arg3 == taxo:field
  else compare arg2 == taxo:field
else compare arg1 == taxo:parent:parent:field
  if arg2 compare arg2 == taxo:parent:field
    if arg3 compare arg3 == taxo:field
  else compare arg2 == taxo:field
```

So the these result examples would yield the following:

```
/viewpath/USA/New-Meadows
```

Would give me every state, county and city in the US called "New Meadows"

```
/viewpath/Idaho
```

Would yield every state, county and city in the dataset named "Idaho"

```
/viewpath/Idaho/New-Meadows
```

Every state, county and city called "New Meadows" in a country called Idaho
Every county and city called "New Meadows" in a state called Idaho in any country
Every city called "New Meadows" in a county called Idaho in any state in any country

...and I can't figure out how to get that functionality to work in Views, nor can I see anywhere that says if it is possible or not.

Comment: Are you using the Hierarchical Select module to assign the terms and, if so, do you have the "Save term lineage" selected?